# Website Blank in IE for 1 Box

Tags: internet-explorer

Using IE8, a user gets only a blank page, but with the favicon, when trying to hit an internal company website hosted on a dedicated server.

Here's what I've tried:

- She successfully remoted onto my desktop and navigated to my website using my computer's IE8
- She can access the website using Firefox
- After enabling a prompt for JS errors, she gets none when accessing the website
- When viewing source, she sees the same HTML as a user who can access the website

User is VPN'd onto the company firewall.

Thanks

Comment: So after using software on **your** laptop, *her* installation of IE8 (on a separate terminal) worked? The two aren't connected, trust me ;)

Comment: We have two computers, A and B. On A, she gets a blankpage to my website. On B (my laptop she remoted onto), she can view my website.

Comment: When you say the site's behind a firewall, how do you mean? Is it running on a local web server?

Comment: behind firewall = it's on a company's intranet. 

I mentioned that in case stackoverflow folks wanted to try to hit my website.

Comment: what version of IE is on your laptop? Did you try "view source" on her IE8? Is her IE8 outside the firewall? What about your PC? Has she tried any other browsers on her PC (ie to prove whether it's a problem with IE specifically or a problem generally on her PC). You definitely need to edit the question to make it clearer what you've tried already, because the wording you have makes it hard to understand the problem, much less offer constructive help.

Comment: Sorry all for my poor & vague problem description. I updated it. Thank you for your criticism